# Reusing the firebase-server-sdk credentials with the REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In the old version of Firebase, my server app written in Java would authenticate with my backend using the secret and the JWT token generator. Then, at anytime, I could call `Firebase.getAuth().getToken()` and reuse that token in an HTTP call as the `auth` parameter.

With the new `firebase-server-sdk`, how would I reuse my limited service account credentials / token with the REST API?

```
Map<String, Object> auth = new HashMap<String, Object>();
auth.put("uid", "server-app");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setDatabaseUrl(Environment.FIREBASE_URL)
            .setServiceAccount(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/keys/dev.json"))
            .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(auth)
            .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

That all works great when I use the SDK to subscribe / write to certain locations - specifically locations that require a `server-app` uid. But I use REST in conjunction in my server app, because I want my server app to make synchronous reads, something Firebase only supports through the REST API.

```
FirebaseRestClient firebaseRest = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Environment.FIREBASE_URL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(final RequestFacade request) {
                        request.addQueryParam("access_token", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken("server-app"));
                    }
                })
                .build().create(FirebaseRestClient.class);
```

I've tried adding both the `access_token` and `auth` param. It seems like that `createCustomToken` method produces a valid JWT, but the REST API isn't responding.

When I pass in that `createCustomToken` return value as the `auth` param, I get the following message:

```
"error" : "Missing claim 'kid' in auth header."
```

When I pass in that `createCustomToken` return value as the `access_token` param, I get the basic `Permission denied` API response.

Is there an easy way to reuse my existing `firebase-server-sdk` credentials in a REST API call?

Answer (score 1):

The token you're attempting to use is a Firebase Authentication ID token - the type which is designed to be passed to the Firebase SDK on a client. The REST API accepts a Firebase access token (just like the ones in previous Firebase clients).

Your authentication is failing because normally the Firebase SDK takes care of turning your ID token into an access token. Your server can *not* do this transition or generate an access token using the Firebase SDK so I recommend using the original [Firebase Token Generator library](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-java) with your Firebase Secret to create access tokens for the REST API. This will work fine even for new Firebase projects created since the I/O release.

Note: In the Console your Database Secret can be found under (Gear Icon) > Project Settings > Database.

Comment: Abe, do you have an update on this since database secrets are now being deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not advised, given the name of the undocumented property, but...

If your SDK has logged in with a serviceAccount, you can use `firebase.auth().INTERNAL.getToken()`, which returns a promised `accessToken` (and `expirationTime`) which then works with the `?access_token` parameter.

Comment: I should add that this is for the node.js SDK.